# SQL group by 7am to 7am

Tags: sql, intervals

How do I simply group by a 24 hour interval from 7am to 7am in a manner similar to:

```
select format(t_stamp,'yyyy-MMM')
from mytable
group by format(t_stamp,'yyyy-MMM')
```

if input is like

```
3,Wed Mar 23 20:40:40 EDT 2022
3,Wed Mar 23 20:40:39 EDT 2022
4,Wed Mar 23 03:36:10 EDT 2022
3,Wed Mar 22 15:46:44 EST 2022
3,Tue Mar 22 04:16:52 EST 2022
4,Sat Mar 22 03:13:08 EDT 2022
3,Sat Mar 22 03:13:05 EDT 2022
4,Sat Mar 21 04:10:36 EDT 2022
```

output should be like

```
 6,  Mar 23
 7,  Mar 22
10,  Mar 21
 4,  Mar 20
```

Comment: What is the integer before the date?  Also. __EDT / EST__ do we care about those subtle differences?

Comment: Please try to be more specific. You mention a 24h interval, but when does the interval start and when does it end? It would help to explain the output. If you work with a specific database system please mention it too.

Comment: Deduct 7 hours then group by date.

Comment: @shawnt00 ref: __(hour(t_stamp) + 17) / 12 % 2__ why not make that an answer and provide complete generic SQL?

Comment: @zipzit I had misread the question as 7am-7pm and 7-pm to 7-am. But as OP didn't specify a platform I didn't exactly want to step into the line of fire of everybody who would object to making guesses. The easiest answer is to adjust by seven hours to align with a regular date value.

Comment: @quickasks. What class are you taking?  This looks like a database class homework assignment.

Comment: I figured it out.
I used date add and formatted for day. Thanks for the help @zipzit

I would like a faster method though. The date format converts to string and hinders the index.